# Magento backend Dashboard is empty when Login?

Tags: magento-1.9

Friends i had installed a Extension called **Update Layout** a purchased extension. after installation i had cleared my cache storage and logged out & logged in. . while logging in the dashboard is showing nothing. so please help me out here. .
i  had attached the snapshot of my login page.

[image: This is my Snapshot]

Comment: Any errors in the log files? Try to clear your cache again...

Comment: tried but it remains the same

Comment: What about your logs?

Comment: Logs???I can't get

Comment: You can find your logs in the var/log folder. (if they are turned on)